# Hide my Linux machine from traceroute but still allow ping

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

i have a linux server running RedHat and i want to make it pingable but invisible to traceroute/tracert.
i set some iptables rules but whatever i try is either block or allow both ping and traceroute.
i could make it work on another machine running FreeBSD using ipfw with the following rule `ipfw add deny icmp from me to any icmptypes 11 out` 
this rule allow me to ping my machine and when the trace reach the machine it skip it and shows *****.
how can i acheave this in redhat using iptables or any other possible way?
thank you!!

Comment: traceroute (and tracepath) use a variety packet of types and methods depending on arguments, operating system, etc. If FreeBSD worked for you, it was just a lucky test combination.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) has many messages that are identified by a "type" field. You need to use 0 and 8 ICMP code types.

```
(0) is for echo-reply
(8) is for echo-request
```

For iptables first set your IP:

```
SERVER_IP="<put_your_ip_here>"
```

Second, allow pings

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s 0/0 -d $SERVER_IP -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -s $SERVER_IP -d 0/0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

An next rule is disable ICMP at all

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0/0 -d $SERVER_IP -j DROP
```

Comment: Blocks a standard ping.